# Tokenize Java InputStream into streams, not Strings

Tags: java, forms, inputstream

I know the Java libraries pretty well, so I was surprised when I realized that, apparently, there's no easy way to do something seemingly simple with a stream. I'm trying to read an HTTP request containing multipart form data (large, multiline tokens separated be delimiters that look like, for example, `------WebKitFormBoundary5GlahTkFmhDfanAn--`), and I want to read until I encounter a part of the request with a given name, and then return an InputStream of that part.

I'm fine with just reading the stream into memory and returning a `ByteArrayInputStream`, because the files submitted should never be larger than 1MB. However, I want to make sure that the reading method throws an exception if the file is larger than 1MB, so that excessively-large files don't fill up the JVM's memory and crash the server. The file data may be binary, so that rules out `BufferedReader.readLine()` (it drops newlines, which could be any of `\r`, `\n`, or `\r\n`, resulting in loss of data).

All of the obvious tokenizing solutions, such as `Scanner`, read the tokens as `String`s, not streams, which could cause `OutOfMemoryError`s for large files--exactly what I'm trying to avoid. As far as I can tell, there's no equivalent to `Scanner` that returns each token as an `InputStream` without reading it into memory. Is there something I'm missing, or is there any way to create something like that myself, using just the standard Java libraries (**no** Apache Commons, etc.), that doesn't require me to read the stream a character at a time and write all of the token-scanning code myself?

---

**Addendum:** Shortly before posting this, I realized that the obvious solution to my original problem was simply to read the full request body into memory, failing if it's too large, and then to tokenize the resulting `ByteArrayInputStream` with a `Scanner`. This is inefficient, but it works. However, I'm still interested to know if there's a way to tokenize an `InputStream` into sub-streams, without reading them into memory, without using extra libraries, and without resorting to character-by-character processing.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible without loading them into memory (the solution you don't want) or saving them to disk (becomes I/O heavy). Tokenizing the stream into separate streams without loading it into memory implies that you can read the stream (to tokenize it) and be able to read it again later. In short, what you want is impossible **unless** your stream is seekable, but these are generally specialized streams for very specific applications and specialized I/O objects, like [`RandomAccessFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html).

Comment: Seeking in the stream isn't necessary if the token streams are read strictly _in order_. The ideal solution would provide one stream at a time, in order, each of which ends when the next delimiter is reached, at which point the next stream can be created.

Comment: @ACE91 I started to type that, but figured it was superfluous. The only reason I could think of for you wanting this was to process the data asynchronously.